# gem_original_require': no such file to load -- timeout (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems

I have installed rubygems. But i m getting before error :

```
[kalselva@ud-test-002 ~]$ gem --help
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- timeout (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/command_manager.rb:7
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:7
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/bin/gem:9
[kalselva@ud-test-002 ~]$
```

Please help me here.